# Statistics test to check for a correlation between two groups

Tags: correlation, data-visualization, dataset

I have the number of dispensed items per year and the cost per item - the graphs *look* as if when the number of dispensed items increase the cost comes down per item (red = cost, blue = number dispensed).  For example,

[image]

[image]

I want to do some a statistical test to see whether or not the number of items dispensed in a year increasing forces the cost down / if they are correlated, but I'm not sure which test to use.

Comment: You may do a trend analysis or a correlation analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the assumptions of randomness, fixed distribution, fixed location, and fixed variation hold, you can perform an independent samples t-test. If the assumptions are violated, try a Mann-Whitney test.

If you are just interested in correlation, try a Pearson test. If the assumptions are violated, try a Spearman test.

If you would like to perform a statistical test with time series in mind, consider a Granger causality test.